# Supporting iOS 4.2 and higher

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to ensure the code I write is supported by iOS 4.2 and higher.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear what are u saying

Comment: Can you please tell what does higher mean? ios6 or future releases?

Comment: So far I would say from 4.3 to say iOS6 .....

Comment: Simply on simulators on xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your Deployment target to be iOS 4.2
That will help Xcode to flag any errors or warnings if you use an API that is not supported from or after 4.2
Also, use 4.2 simulator while building the application.

Ultimately you would need to test on a real iOS device having iOS 4.2 to be 100% sure that it works.

Comment: ok, thanks i see. I have set target to 4.3. (it was 4.3 instead of 4.2 sorry).

Answer (score 1):

Your code most probably will work on newer OS versions but an easy way would be to set the deployment target to iOS 4.2 or higher and then run in the simulator. This would easily tell you if it could build without warnings.

You can set deployment target in the Build settings of your app. Hope this helps.